# How to check if a LoadXml() on a XmlDocument instance went wrong without using XmlException

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have to fix some code that looks like this:

```
XmlDocument XmlFoo = null;

try{
    SomeUntrappedWCFCalls();
    SomeUntrappedStringParsing();
    SomeUntrappedXMLParsing();
    ..
    XmlFoo = new XmlDocument();
    XmlFoo.LoadXml(SomeXml);
    ..
    SomeUntrappedWCFCalls();
    SomeUntrappedStringParsing();
    SomeUntrappedXMLParsing();
}
(Exception ex){

      CodeThatDealsWithPartOfTheExceptionsRaisedAbove(); 
      ..
      //Need to check if the LoadXml() went wrong
      ..
      CodeThatDealsWithPartOfTheExceptionsRaisedAbove();
}
```

How could I properly check in the exception handling section <sup>(*)</sup>, if `XmlFoo` is a new instance of `XmlDocument` but the `LoadXml()` went wrong for a load/parse error?

I have two constrains:

1. I can't wrap the `LoadXML()` inside an `XmlException` because all the error handling are handled inside the Exception code.
2. I can't create an `XmlException` just before the general Exception because there are other Xml files parsed before and after the XmlFoo parsing.

Is it a safe and inelegant workaround to just count the number of Nodes with something like:

```
if (XmlFoo.ChildNodes.Count == 0){..
```

or do I need some other variables to check the `LoadXML()` parsing status in some way?

Comment: *Why* can't you just trap XmlException? Why can't you parse in an initial try/catch block, and then deal with the document afterwards? This question is very vague.

Comment: See my answer, guess you´re not that familiar with exception handling in C# :)

Comment: Well you've *left* us guessing, by not giving much guidance about the extent to which we can change the code. Even if other exceptions can happen before or after the parsing, that doesn't stop you from isolating *just* exceptions that occur during parsing.

Comment: Well, i don´t see a reason why not to use proper exception handling. Did you check my answer? The XmlDocument will be empty if any error happens durch LoadXml, so you can jsut check if it´s empty if you prefer.

Comment: @systempuntoout: Well if the code is "not yours" how are we meant to know the extent to which you can change it? No, your question is *far* from clear enough for a simple answer.

Comment: @systempuntoout: We'll have to agree to disagree then. I think this is a poorly asked question with far too little context.

Comment: @systempuntoout In your code example you had a comment within the catch block that said "need to check if LoadXml went wrong". Just to clarify - can you actualy perform any checks at that place or arn´t you allowed to do any edits there?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've tried to add some context.

Comment: @Mecaveli I'm allowed to do any edits I want (with less risks that I can)

Comment: You don't use exceptions for non-exceptional cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your horrible constraints, I would view the cleanest solution as:

```
bool parsingAttempted = false;
bool parsingSucceeded = false;
try
{
    XmlFoo = new XmlDocument();
    parsingAttempted = true;
    XmlFoo.LoadXml(SomeXml);
    parsingSucceeded = true;
}
```

Now you can check for three situations:

- Error before parsing was attempted: `parsingAttempted` is false
- Error during parsing: `parsingAttempted` is true, `parsingSucceeded` is false
- Parsing succeeded: `parsingSucceeded` is true

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here, but after reading your comments with Jon Skeet, maybe something simple as this could help you:

```
XmlDocument XmlFoo = null;
bool loading = false;
try{
    ..
    XmlFoo = new XmlDocument();
    loading = true;
    XmlFoo.LoadXml(SomeXml);
    loading = false;
    ..
}
catch (Exception ex){

   if(loading)
   {
      //something went wrong while loading XML
   }   .. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you can´t just catch the XmlException, have alook at this:

```
XmlDocument XmlFoo = null;

try
{
    XmlFoo = new XmlDocument();
    XmlFoo.LoadXml(SomeXml);
}
(XmlException ex)
{
    // Loadxml went wrong
}
(Exception ex)
{
    // Some other Error
}
```

Or you can also use:

```
XmlDocument XmlFoo = null;

try
{
    XmlFoo = new XmlDocument();
    XmlFoo.LoadXml(SomeXml);
}
(Exception ex)
{
    if(ex is XmlException)
        // LoadXml Error
    else
        // Some other Error
}
```

Comment: Simply take the try...catch and wrap it arround the LoadXml only and there you go. If you´ve any trouble with that then the answers of Nikola Davidovic and Jon Skeet are a good alternative.